# Material UI Table with Drop Down inside a column

Tags: reactjs

I want to insert a select drop down inside material ui table as part of row. Can you please share a reference as to how to perform this using React.

Answer (score 7):

In material able you have a special feature "lookup".

Please refer to the following code:

```
 const columns = [
 {
  title: "Name",
  field: "Name",
  value:Name,
  lookup:
   {
     1:"John"
     2:"Jessica"
   }       
  },
 ]
```

Comment: You can see more details at https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

Answer (score -2):

```
 const columns = [
 {
  title: "Name",
  field: "Name",
  lookup:
   {
     1:"John"
     2:"Jessica"
   }       
 ]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.